# Is there a way to count the party list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to create a field in my Phone Call activity that holds the number of recipients of the call. The recipient field is a party list field and I need to use a javascript function to count the party list and save the count in that field. 
Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Party list fields are rendered as lookup, but they can hold more than 1 value.
Assuming for example that your field is `to` you can get the count with this code:

```
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue() != null) {
   var partycount = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue().length;
}
```